# What does this notation, used in Markov Chains, mean?

Tags: statistics, notation, markov-chains, markov-process

In my module on Markov processes, the following notation is used:
$$
p_{ij}^{(m,n)} = P(X_n = j \mid X_m = i) \quad \text{where } \: m<n \\
p_j^{(n)} = P(X_n = j) \\
p_{ij}^{(k)} = \: ???
$$

Does anyone know what $p_{ij}^{(k)}$ denotes?

Comment: I would think that $p_{ij}^{(k)}$ is the $k$-step transition probability from the initial state, i.e., $p_{ij}^{(0,k)}$.

Comment: @JKnecht Explain your question... What don't you understand about that?

Comment: Acknowledged. In future I'll ensure to do so in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
p_{ij}^{(k)} = \Pr(X_{n+k} = j \mid X_n = i)
$$
This is the probability that the process will be in state $j$ at $k$ units of time from now, given that it is in state $i$ now, the $k$-step transition probability.